# map data from one column to another

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two DataFrames d1 and d2.

d1:

```
       category  value
0        a      4
1        b      9
2        c     14
3        d     19
4        e     24
5        f     29
```

d2:

```
   one two
0  NaN   a
1  NaN   a
2  NaN   c
3  NaN   d
4  NaN   e
5  NaN   a
```

I want to map values from d1 to 'one' column in d2 using category marker form d1.
this should return me:

```
   one two
0   4    a
1   4    a
2  14    c
3  19    d
4  24    e
5   4    a
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: Google `pandas join` and/or `pandas merge`

Comment: is not so easy as i thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df2['one'] = df2['two'].map(df1.set_index('category')['value'])
```